# Office 2007 support for Exchange 2010 Personal Archive

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

Does anyone know if Microsoft will be updating Outlook 2007 to support Personal Archives in Exchange 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a number of response in forum posts from MS staff that a patch for Oulook 2007 is being developed to allow it access to Personal Archives, but it's unlikely to be released before Office 2010 release.